# Storing all information from a directory into one list

Tags: python, list, csv, directory, operating-system

Hello I am trying to store my directory into one list.  I am able to call the directory with this code:

```
import os
path = r'c:/users/blahblahblah'
listing= os.listing(path)
for infile in listing:
 print "current file is: "+infile";
```

This outputs the each file from the directory.  I want to call each file in the directory and store the contents of each file into a list.  All the files are csv.

Thus after that I am having trouble calling the contents of each of those files and storing them as a list.  Been at it a bit. Frustrated to say the least.

(My end goal is to be able to store these files in a sqlite3 db (which means a dataframe and dict won't suffice...trust me I've tried that...) Every step regarding the sqlite3 seems good to go.

Comment: (1) No need for the `r` in the path definition. (2) Nobody _calls_ files. (3) Use module `csv` to read file contents.

Comment: `os.listing` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest:

`file_contents_list = [open(filepath).read() for filepath in os.listdir(path)]`

This isn't great practice because it technically leaves file handles open but it should be fine for your purposes.